# Push notification to millions of device + Apns + node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, notifications, apple-push-notifications

My application stack is ios(front-end) and node.js(back-end). I have to send notification to devices.  In my node.js part im using apns module to send notification, its working fine......

Now i have to send Mass notification like at a time consider i have 10,000 devices to notified, the logic what im following is

I'm looping through 10,000 devices and calling apns provider.

**1.Why this for loop approach**

I have to store each notification details in my mongodb collection, so i followed this approach.

The problem is the notification is received by some devices and that too very late(next day).

I read the link also
https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started
saying apns will reject.

Is the above approach is correct also any way to make all notification deliverer.

Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process each individual notification before/after it is sent I would instead recommend a design change from a loop and have you look at [job queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_queue) instead.

With this design pattern, instead of your only step being to loop over notifications and send via APN, you push these notification into a queue/messaging system and have workers which pull from the queue and process (send via APN and write to mongo) the notifications. The nice part of this design is that as your application grows you can add on more workers to handle the increased load without rewriting your application/architecture. Once you have it built it may look something like this:

[image]

I personally use [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) for my job queue, but that decision is something you need to research on your own. For example if you don't want to manage the messaging system you could look into something like [AWS Simple Queue Service](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).

Answer (score 0):

I think looping through 10,000 devices ids and calling APNS provider is not the right way forward. The documentations strictly says here [node-apn readme file](https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn/blob/master/doc/apn.markdown#readme) to reuse **apn.Provider** rather than recreate it every time to achieve the best possible performance.

If you send notification using arrays of device ids rather than just a device id then you will get a response from the APNS mentioning all the details for each device.